# Write file creation date to a text file, in a single line

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, creation

This may be easy but it's driving me nuts (2 whole hours spent already! I've tried dozens of things!).

I just need a **single line bat script** that reads a given file's creation date and writes it to a text file.

I've tried using the `dir /T:C` command, but it writes way too much info. For example:

```
dir /T:C "E:\TEST\test.mkv" >"E:\TEST\test.txt"
```

Writes this in the `text.txt` file:

```
Le volume dans le lecteur E s'appelle xxxxxxxx
Le numéro de série du volume est xxxxxxxx

Répertoire de E:\TEST

11/03/2018  20:45     1 947 028 131 test.mkv
               1 fichier(s)    1 947 028 131 octets
               0 Rép(s)  64 368 631 808 octets libres
```

And I'm only interested in the "11/03/2018  20:45" part.

EDIT: I could also settle for the previous dir /T:C syntax if we could add a bit of code to keep only line #6 of the output and write it to the same text file.

Comment: `For /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %A in (\`wmic datafile where "name='c:\\windows\\notepad.exe'" get creationdate
/format:list\`) Do Echo %A`

Comment: Thanks Mark. That seems to work... except that since your syntax uses apostrophes instead of double quotes, now I have a problem with paths containing apostrophes. 'c:\\windows\\notepad.exe' works well, but how about 'c:\\test\\L'amour.mkv' ? I have tried escaping the apostrophes ( 'c:\\test\\L^'amour.mkv' ), but it doesn't work...

Comment: See `for /?`. `UseBackq` changes what characters do. You have to suit it to your input data.

Comment: In the `wmic` command line, try to remove the outer quotes and then to replace the apostrophes by quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, which technically does and doesn't use only one line in the batch file, and uses VBScript.

```bat
<!-- :
@("%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf">"E:\TEST\test.txt")&Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
Set o=CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set f=o.GetFile("E:\TEST\test.mkv")
s=Left(f.DateCreated,Len(f.DateCreated)-3)
</Script></Job>
```

To remain on topic however here are some exactly one line batch file examples.

This method leverages `powershell.exe`:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoP "'{0:dd/MM/yyy}' -F(Get-Date(GI 'E:\TEST\test.mkv').CreationTime)">"E:\TEST\test.txt"
```

And this one uses `WMIC.exe`:

```bat
@For /F %%I In ('WMIC DataFile Where Name^="E:\\TEST\\test.mkv" Get CreationDate 2^>NUL^|Find "."')Do @Set "d=%%~nI"&(Call Echo %%d:~6,2%%/%%d:~4,2%%/%%d:~,4%% %%d:~8,2%%:%%d:~10,2%%)>"E:\TEST\test.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks Compo. I especially like your last suggestion. The problem I have now is that your variable "Name" containing the path to the file is defined with apostrophes instead of double quotes. And some of my paths do have apostrophes. I have tried escaping them (^') but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Updated the WMIC version, @JoseHidalgo. _I'd be interested to know how the other example(s) work for you too._

Comment: Thanks @Compo, but I can't make your updated WMIC version work yet. I've only replaced both of your paths with my own paths (the first one with double backslashes and the second one with single backslashes), but the text file isn't created.

Comment: Turns out your WMIC version works, but only for very basic paths (e.g. E:\\TEST\\test.mkv). Maybe it doesn't like long paths with spaces and stuff?

Comment: Here's an example of a path that doesn't work:
"E:\\VIDEO\\FILMS\\Adventureland (2009) - 1080p\\Adventureland (2009) 1080p BluRay x265.mkv"

Comment: @Jose, your question was specific, you've now changed your filename twice since I answered. I have edited it again, but please be aware that I do not have a PC and am therefore unable to test the vast majority of what I post on this site. _(your filename was not specified as 'could be anything')_ BTW, the `Dir` output is not consistent accross different Users/PC's/Locales/Languages, hence the reason I haven't offered a method of just parsing your specific output, _as it may not match that of future readers_.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I just assumed that any offered solution would be valid for any path in my hard drive. I guess I was wrong. I'm happy to announce that your updated line works for most paths. I still had trouble with paths containing commas, but I treated them manually, so ultimately it worked. Thanks for providing a working solution!

Comment: Done now. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@For /f "Tokens=1,2 Delims= " %%A in ('dir /T:C "E:\TEST\test.mkv" ^| Find /I "Test.mkv"') Do Echo %%A %%B >output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to work at the moment. I may need to state that the single line itself must be inside a .bat script, not from the command line. Maybe it changes something?